# C error, "expected declaration specifier"

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct _lnode{
    struct _lnode *next;
    unsigned short row;
    unsigned short column;
    short data;
}lnode;

typedef struct _llist{
    struct _lnode *header;
    unsigned int size;

}llist;

lnode* add(lnode *lnode, lnode *newNode);
```

I have this code in .h file and if I am trying to compile then it complains "expected declaration specifier" at the line where I declare "add" function. I recently changed IDE to Eclipse CDT and this code worked just fine on my Linux machine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the name of the parameter `lnode`, it confuses the compiler:

```
lnode* add(lnode *oldNode, lnode *newNode);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lnode* add(lnode *node, lnode *newNode);
```

don't name your variable like your typedef

and in the prototype, you don't have to name them at all

```
lnode* add(lnode*, lnode *);
```

Comment: It was so obvious I didn't see it :S

Comment: it is just not neccessary, you can do it if you like